# How can I control my robot fanuc m10 step by step in real time?

Tags: ros, fanuc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't get the robot to move, only to watch his present position using rviz. Is it possible to do without moveit ?
Or if not real-time, step by step with the minimum of delay?
Installed Ros on Ubuntu 16.04. As an alternative to the real robot (waiting for delivery is an option from Fanuc) use Roboguide. Karell compiled according to the instructions from the wiki and downloaded all .pc and .tp files to the controller. Launch ros.tp.
On the computer run

```
roslaunch fanuc_m10ia_support robot_state_vizualize_m10ia.launch robot_ip:=127.0.0.1 use_bswap:=false
```

Everything appears correctly!
Next run

```
roslaunch fanuc_m10ia_support robot_interface_streaming_m10ia.launch robot_ip:=127.0.0.1 use_bswap:=false
```

The controller appears RSTA connected and RREL connected.
I tried to write in various topics, but nothing happens

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271864/how-can-i-control-my-robot-fanuc-m10-step-by-step-in-real-time?/) by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
Can you explain what you've already done? How did you install things, which software are you using, etc? Please *edit* your original question for that.

If you can't get the robot to move *at all*, then something is wrong, because `fanuc_driver` should be able to do that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
As to real-time / minimum delay: that is possible, but you will probably not like the performance very much. Fanuc robots don't have any external motion interface, and are not really well suited for this kind of thing.

If you need actual real-time, custom development with something like ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
.. DPM might be more suited.

I would also recommend you install [fanuc_driver_exp](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp) instead of `fanuc_driver`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
Thanks for the update. Can you explain how you can run RoboGuide on Ubuntu? Or is `127.0.0.1` an example IP?

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-09-29**:
127.0.0.1 it's example IP

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-12-26**:
@gvdhoorn is DPM Fanuc's analog to Kuka's RSI?  Performance-wise are there any major differences?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-27**:
@BrettHemes: I wish it was. It's a real-time interface, but only for Cartesian *corrections* in a very limited volume around a fixed point (or at least, that's one of the methods of operation). There are a few other modes, but nothing that truely solves the Fanuc-is-missing-a-proper-external-..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-27**:
..-motion-interface.

I was sort-of hopeful that J802 would finally solve all our problems (it's even called "Remote Sensor Interface", ie: RSI), but so far it only seems to be a state reporting solution (ie: RSI with `sendonly==true`). No motion commanding there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-27**:\

> is DPM Fanuc's analog to Kuka's RSI

Ok so just re-read your question: yes, in a way, DPM is Fanuc's RSI (if you see RSI really only as the real-time correction interface based on some (external) sensor). But RSI is typically used as a complete control interface, and DPM is definitely *not* that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The controller appears `RSTA connected` and `RREL connected`.

That is good, that means that everything is connected.

> I tried to write in various topics, but nothing happens

That is expected, as the driver exposes a [FollowJointTrajectory](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/control_msgs/html/action/FollowJointTrajectory.html) action interface. It does not listen to any topics.

The `/joint_state` topic (for instance) is for reporting current state of the robot, not for controlling it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-09-29**:
I need to interact with FollowJointTrajectory use actionlib? Or something else? Could you explain me more how to send a command to the robot?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:\

> I need to interact with FollowJointTrajectory use actionlib

yes. That's it.

That's all there is to it.

But again: use `fanuc_driver_exp`. Not `fanuc_driver`.

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-09-29**:
fanuc_driver_exp it's just simply an updated driver for the robot controller? or am I mistaken?

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-09-29**:
Could you give me an example of interaction with FollowJointTrajectory?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:\

> fanuc_driver_exp it's just simply an updated driver for the robot controller?

yes, that is correct. It's 100% compatible with the ROS side of `fanuc_driver`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:\

> Could you give me an example of interaction with FollowJointTrajectory?

There's no example specifically for this driver (as the concept is so generic in ROS that wouldn't make much sense). You could perhaps look at the `test_move.py` script in the `universal_robot/ur_driver` package. See ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:
.. [ros-industrial/universal_robot/ur_driver/test_move.py](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/kinetic-devel/ur_driver/test_move.py).

Make sure to update the joint names, and set proper values for the velocities, not just `time_from_start`. The Karel code uses the `velocity` ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-30**:
.. field from the [JOINT_TRAJ_PT](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rep-ros-i/blob/retrospective_simple_msg/rep-ixxxx.rst#joint-traj-pt), not the `duration`.